# Consume SSO/SOAP response

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, single-sign-on

I have this SSO/SOAP WebService that I need to consume some info and I'm not used with C#/ASP.NET so I don't know how to get the response to an usable object.

This is the return from the SOAP

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <RetornaEstadosResponse xmlns="http://WebService-MultiLogin-2013/">
      <RetornaEstadosResult>
        <EstadosMDL>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Nome>string</Nome>
          <Sigla>string</Sigla>
        </EstadosMDL>
        <EstadosMDL>
          <ID>int</ID>
          <Nome>string</Nome>
          <Sigla>string</Sigla>
        </EstadosMDL>
      </RetornaEstadosResult>
    </RetornaEstadosResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I have the object that I want to populate with the returns:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace Library
{
    public class Estados
    {
        //Here i'm creating the object
        private AdminMaster.RetornaEstadosPorMarca.Estados ssoEstados = new AdminMaster.RetornaEstadosPorMarca.Estados();

        public List<Estados> lstEstado = new List<Estados>();

        #region Propriedades
            public int ID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Nome
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string Sigla
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        #endregion

        #region Métodos
            /// <summary>
            /// Lista Todos os Estados
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public void Listar(Library.Estados objEstados)
            {
                //Here i'm calling the function that will return me the States(response)
                ssoEstados.RetornaEstadosPorMarca(Library.Configuracoes.ChaveSSO, Library.Configuracoes.Marca);
            }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now, how to I read/consume that response and put that in my Estados object to use on the project?

EDIT

I tried this:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

// Create an XmlReader
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(respSSO)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("EstadosMDL");
    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    string genre = reader.Value;

    return genre;
 }
```

and got this error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Library.Configuracoes.get_ChaveSSO() +95
   Library.Estados.Listar() +89
   AdminMaster.SiteMaster.ListaEstados() +113
   AdminMaster.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

Comment: Get your SOAP response as a string and use an XmlReader to parse it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mausimo but i need to use it with the other method, it is a client request.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this "i need to use it with the other method, it is a client request"? Please explain further, I do not understand your problem. What is hosting the SOAP web service and what is consuming it?

Comment: Sorry buddy, i misunderstood your answer, when i read it twice i got the idea.

Basically i would transform it to a string and parse as a XML later ?

Comment: Yes. Generally the response you get back from a SOAP request will be an XML formatted string. You then take the XmlReader and parse the string into the XML elements and deal with them as you are parsing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i realized when i read it again ! Sorry once more.

I tried only take one value from it but i'm not sure how i would read the second child(EstadosMDL), which would be repeated.

Code on original question.

Comment: I added an answer and the relevent code from the msdn example. The switch will parse each XML element. You can have multiples elements etc. Please mark my answer if it solves your question.

Comment: I'm gonna try it, thanks in advance buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the response you get back from a SOAP request will be an XML formatted string. You then take the XmlReader and parse the string into the XML elements and deal with them as you are parsing.

XmlReader: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

This example shows how to parse each node via a switch:

```
// Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It worked with the example but with my XML won't work because of the many childs i have on it, how could i access it ?

Like, in my example i have:

    rootsoap12:Envelope
        soap12:Body
            RetornaEstadosResponse
                RetornaEstadosResult
                    EstadosMDL.

How could i reach the EstadosMDL childs and loop trough all of the EstadosMDL ?

Comment: reader.Read() reads the next element. Having Read() in a while loop should step through all elements. What is happening when you step through the code?

Comment: When i reach soap:Envelope i end up on case XmlNodeType.Element and i get an error: Invalid character name, because of the ':'.

Is there a way to go straight to EstadosMDL ?

Comment: Pre-format your string. Remove everything before: <RetornaEstadosResponse xmlns="http://WebService-MultiLogin-2013/"> and everything after:</RetornaEstadosResponse>. Then use the XmlReader.

Comment: Yeah, how could i do that ?

Comment: The String class supports this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.aspx. Using methods like IndexOf(), SubString(), Remove(), Replace() etc.

Comment: Hey @Mausimo, is there any other way to do this ?